# Python File I/O issue: Bypassing For Loop?

Tags: python, io

```
def findWord(word):
    f = open("words.txt", "r")
    given_line = f.readlines()
    for line in f:
        if str(word) in line:
            part = line[0]
            ## print(line+"\n"+str(word)+" is a "+part)
            return True
        else:
            return False
    print("fail")
    f.close()

def partSpeech(inX):
    f = open("words.txt", "a")
    inX = inX.split()
    for i in inX:
        i = i.lower()
        if(findWord(i) == False):
            if "ify" in i[-3:] or "ate" in i[-3:] or "ize" in i[-3:] or "ing" in i[-3:] or "en" in i[-2:] or "ed" in i[-2:]:
                f.write("\nV"+i)
            elif "ment" in i[-4:] or "ion" in i[-3:] or "acy" in i[-3:] or "ism" in i[-3:] or "ist" in i[-3:] or "ness" in i[-3:] or "ity" in i[-3:] or "or" in i[-2:] or "y" in i[-1:]:
                f.write("\nN"+i)
            elif "ly" in i[-2:]:
                f.write("\nD"+i)
        else:
            print(i+" was already in the database.")
```

Essentially, my issue with the above happens at "for line in f:". The problem is that, after putting numerous markers (prints to determine where it's getting) throughout the code, the for loop isn't even ran! I don't understand, really, whether or not it's just that line or f aren't being counted or what, but.

The goal is to, in this snippet, take a bunch of words, loop them through a system that checks whether or not they're already in the given text file (the part I'm having issues with) and then, if they're not, append them with a part of speech tag.

EDIT: I'm not getting an error at all, it's just that it's not running the For Loop like it should. Every function is called at some point or another, partSpeech is called toward the end with a small list of words.

EDIT 2: PROGRESS! Sort of. The text file was empty, so it wasn't reading any line whatsoever. Now, however, it's not taking into account whether or not the words are already there. It just skips over them.

Comment: Do you really call the def partSpeech() somewhere?

Comment: "*The text file was empty*" 

Answer (score 0):

First off, delete this line:

```
given_line = f.readlines()
```

This is reading the contents of the file into an unused `given_line` variable and leaving `f` positioned at the end of the file. Your `for` loop therefore has nothing to loop over.

---

Your `findWord()` function is doing a number of odd/problematic things, any of which might be causing the behavior you're assuming means the for loop isn't even running. Here's a possible re-implementation:

```
def findWord(word):
  # it seems odd to pass a "word" parameter that isn't a str, but if you must handle that
  # case you only need to do the cast once
  word = str(word)
  # always use the with statement to handle resources like files
  # see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/
  with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
      if word in line:
        return True
    return False # only return False after the loop; once we've looked at every line
    # no need to call f.close(), the with statement does it for us
```

Comment: Same issue as before. I even added a f.seek(0) just in case to try and get the position-marker back at the start.

Comment: @JacobDavis updated my answer; I think your `findWord()` function isn't doing what you intend.

Comment: HOLY HELL! You got it to work! Don't laugh, but the primary issue was the return False part being tabbed one too far to the right. I hate myself for that, hahah. Thanks, man! (fyi: it wasn't printing/going through the loop because the text file was empty before)

Comment: No problem, it's an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 0):

`for line in f:` never runs because you have already read the file contents and the cursor is at the end of the file.

You should do:

`for line in given_line:`

Or you could put this statement just before your for loop:

`f.seek(0)`

It places the cursor back at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Both of these don't seem to fix the issue. Even together they don't-- I really don't understand what's going on here with the For Loop skipping.